# Digitally stored data world total history?

Tags: storage

Storage clusters now reach 1TiB/s speed ([cern](https://www.home.cern/news/news/computing/exabyte-disk-storage-cern), [ceph](https://ceph.io/en/news/blog/2024/ceph-a-journey-to-1tibps/)) so I was wondering: when did the world total stored digital data reach a terabyte? Was there research on the topic? The System/360 in 1964 shipped with tape drives at least 45MB capacity ([source](https://www.core77.com/posts/108573/A-Storage-Cabinet-Based-on-the-IBM-2401)) at which point you only need a few ten thousand reels in existence to reach a terabyte. So I am wondering... do we have some estimate when? Is there statistics on reels sold etc?

I found data from much, much later (starting 1986) so certainly some research was done into this.

Comment: What exactly is the question? Transfer speed as noted in the first sentence, or storage as mentioned later?

Comment: Storage capacity. I was just curious how many years passed from "the world now stores a terabyte" to "fairly everyday clusters can move that amount in a second".

Comment: I'm going to be a bit mischievous and ask what you mean by "digitally stored data". The data in books are stored digitally (excepting the illustrations). Egyptian hieroglyphs are digital.

Comment: @JeremyP, I think I follow your meaning, but a more appropriate word would be "discrete" rather than "digital" (which is a very overloaded word in this context). Also, the characters of written natural languages are themselves discrete, but the actual meaning usually isn't (and the meaning isn't fully encoded in the text, but partly in the understandings of speakers of that language).

Comment: You are asking about electonically stored digital data because books are digital too.

Comment: Sign language is done with the fingers, which are digits, therefore sign language is "digital".  But that's very obviously not the intended meaning in this question. [As the word is commonly used today](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/digital), most people do not consider physically printed documents to be digital storage.

Comment: Maybe a better way tp phrase the question is to estimate historical global totals, over time, of both a) electronically-stored  and b) non-electronically-stored digital data (documents, punchcards, etc.)

Comment: @Steve Your argument also applies to electronically stored digital data. Even the text on this web page is partly encoded in the understanding of the speakers of 21st century English.

Comment: @JeremyP, agreed. I've forgotten my exact thread of thought, but I think I was alluding to the fact that "data" is usually considered to exclude the text of natural language. So hieroglyphs may be discrete symbols (if writing style is ignored), but on the wall of the pyramid they aren't conventionally regarded as "digitally stored data".

Comment: Digitally stored data world total history what?

Comment: Do "stored data" and "machine readable" refer to the same thing?

Comment: In a similar vein, [revenue generated by hard drive sales recently crossed the trillion-dollar mark](https://www.techspot.com/news/101582-hdd-revenue-retrospect-charting-nearly-70-years-hard.html).

Comment: that's ... inflation.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A TiB is not a lot. I would think that amount was already hit with punch cards way before the first digital computers were used. Wikipedia [notes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punched_card#20th_century):

> "By 1937... IBM had 32 presses at work in Endicott, N.Y., printing, cutting and stacking five to 10 million punched cards every day."

At 80 characters per card that adds up to 4-800 MiB per day or up to 250 GiB/a. That's only one of IBM's many punch card print shops and IBM being only one manufacturer - at that time far from owning the market like much later.

I'd say that terrabyte was already hit with punch cards in 1937 alone :))

Likewise repeated with tapes already in the 1950s and so on. By 1975 a single mainframe installation, like at a bank clearing center, insurance or utilities company, would get near that storage with 30-100 disk drives online, 100+ MiB each, plus a relational amount of packs stored. Tapes not included.

Comment: Some even older digital data that is definitely not printed text - reels on music boxes, music sheets for player pianos and more complicated music boxes, and programming cards for jacquard looms.  Ten million player pianos worldwide, each with 10 music rolls containing 3 minute songs at 100beats per minute for piano (i.e. 88 bits or 11 bytes per second, 1100 bytes per song), and you've got at least 110GB of digitally stored music by the 1910's for certain.  The timing of the rolls is analogue but the notes (on/off) are definitely digital.

Comment: @JasonPatterson True, but I would see that as an extreme stretch to the question.  Digital storage in sense of the question is useless without data processing -which requires more than just duplication (production) and execution (playing), as that only qualifies as recording. In contrast punch card equipment provides all basic operations for data processing since the late 1920s. Everything we do today is already possible with 1930s punch card equipment - of course eventually not fast enough to make all of it  useful (e.g. running DOOM on a D10 :))

Comment: The data for the 1890 census was recorded on punched cards, and tabulated by automatic machinery.  They counted about 62 million people.  At 80 bytes per person, that's about 5 gigabytes.  If it grows exponentially, it might reach 1Tb before 1937.

Comment: @WalterMitty  Unfortunately. most of the 1890 census was lost to a fire in 1921.  That aside, cumulatively, the censuses probably reached 1TB after 1940, but combined with other digital stores (such as state censuses, etc.), the total may have reached 1TB by 1930 or earlier.

Comment: @WalterMitty I would agree that it was already reached (short) before 1937, but 1937 where I have reference allowing a safe estimate. By just counting punch cards it may have been as early as 1920. Though, cards without the ability to process do not close the loop. While sorters were available as early as 1900 and counting tabulators in 1910, it was the 1920s that brought them all (Alpha printer 1922, subtracting tabulator 1928, 80 column card 1928, multiplying punch, 1931, negative numbers with BK in 1931). Think the 1931 Packard or 193 D11. **It's not data without the ability to process it**

Comment: Also unfortunately, Herman Hollerith's company went under.  It was bough5 out and rechristened International Business Machines.

Comment: @WalterMitty Not really, sure, he lost some business by a classic IBM move of charging his customers way to high prices, but it didn't went under, but got sold for some 1.2 M$ in 1911 plus another 200 k$ in 'consulting fees' over 10 years - plus continued patent payments. I would say quite notable in 1911.maybe not Rockefeller but for sure within the top 0.01% in the US. Also, it took until 1924 before CTR was renamed IBM - and a good decade until no more business was done using the CTR label.

Answer (score 17):

While there is an answer already, I'll put things into a historical perspective with a few data points.

The first time humanity had ~1 TB of stored data was most likely around 250-200 BCE. The Library of Alexandria alone held up to 700,000 scrolls, and it was the largest out of many. Athens, Rome, India and China had extensive written collections at the time (28 libraries in Rome alone). There were also private collections beside libraries.

By 1500, at least 9 million books had been printed in Europe, meaning that Europe alone held over 1 TB of data in a printed form. This number can be higher depending on how many books were bibles, which contain much more text than the average book (3.3 MB for the Gutenberg version).

In 1876, the US alone held at least [12 million books](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/The-Growth-of-Research-Collections.-Downs/77e07adc872f4472de1cca43914cc0751ad4e543) in public libraries, for 5-10 TB. The US was ~1/10 of European and ~1/40 of global population at the time, and libraries aren't everything. So total printed data was likely over 1 PB.

In 1963, total data in paper book libraries was estimated at [450 terabytes](https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.141.3585.1067). Total data was 20-100 PB.

Conclusion: For tape storage to reach 1 TiB, at any point in the 20th century, it would have to represent only ~0.01% of total data. From that, the general answer is that, for most major postwar data storage technologies, 1 TiB data was most likely reached within the first year of commercialization.

Comment: The library at Alexandria was also an object lesson on the need for offsite backups :-)

Comment: @another-dave, it's also a lesson that it takes more than one disaster to be suffered before such backups actually occur!

Comment: To be fair, from what I've read, part of the reason the Library of Alexandria didn't recover, despite efforts to rebuild, was that competitors *had* arisen and *did* provide off-site backups for most if not all of what was stored there (which replacement documents were sourced from), altering the value proposition of a trip to Alexandria for academics who lived closer to one of the other libraries. Much of what we've lost was lost for reasons much more wide-ranging than a single library archive being lost.

Comment: In fact, Alexandria had distributed offsite backups, so to speak. "Antony replaced the losses of the fire during the Alexandrine War with copies made from the library at Pergamum, and libraries in gymnasia or simply founded for citizens abound during that period in the Greek world, they're in like literally every city of any size. If anything at all was lost it was almost certainly mainly critical commentaries on various authors, as well as catalogs of their works[...] Pretty much everything else of value would have existed elsewhere." http://tinyurl.com/retroale